# Is there any way to send Notifications to users in a different tenant using Company Communicator App

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

How to make use of the Azure Bot Service in one Domain and communicate with the MSTeams chat in different tenant or domain.

I have created a Company Communicator App using the Deployment Guide in a different tenant and this App should send one way notifications to MSTeams Chat in another tenant.

How does the users in a different tenant can be accessed from a different tenant/Azure Subscription?

Comment: You can send message to multi tenant by marking the App as multi tenant while registration of the app. Could you please check the the 10 point [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/create-a-bot-for-teams#with-an-azure-subscription).

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT Already the App Registraton config is in Multi tenant. I have tried to send to the Chatbot in a different tenant but message is not sent. I hope there are still more configurations to be one !

Comment: Could you please follow the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/create-a-bot-for-teams#with-an-azure-subscription) to register the bot. Try if that helps.

Comment: @Nanda When the bot receives the invoke message, it can identify the user and tenant from userId and tenantId as per this [section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/create-a-bot-for-teams#bots-in-teams-meetings) in the document.